# Is there a way to print strings pointed to by array of char pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printing

I'm trying to write a parse function that calls another function getword() which breaks up a given string into words. Calling getword() advances the string given to getword to the next word delimited by spaces.

```
void parse(char *s, char **p) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*s != -1 && *s != '&' && *s != '\n' && *s != ';' && *s != '\0') {
       p[i] = s;
       i++;
       getword(s);
    }

}
```

After running the calling program, I am wanting to print out the strings that the char pointers in array p point to. Is this at all possible?

I tried :

```
printf("%s\n", (**p));
```

in the calling program, but it only prints out "(null)".

**EDIT**:

I attempted to use the following loop after inputting the string "Hello World":

```
for(i=0; i< MAXITEM; i++)
    printf("%s\n", p[i]);
```

But the program returns:

"

(null)
(null)
(null)..."

Two blank newlines then 98 (null)'s. Are the words "Hello" and "World" actually stored in those two blank newlines, or are they actually not getting stored in **p?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Write a loop.

Comment: So you have a string like `"foo\nbar&baz"` and you wanna turn it into `{ "foo", "bar", "baz" }`? Try `strtok_r()`. And I don't see why you're checking the current character against `-1`.

Comment: @n.m. I added a for loop to loop through and print the elements, however when entering "Hello World" at the prompt, it returns 2 newlines and then 98 (null)'s. (MAXITEM = 100) is p[0] = "Hello" and p[1] = "World" or are they both holding a blank?

Comment: @H2C03 I copy and pasted the looping condition from another file and forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define getword(s)  while (*s && *s != ' ') ++s; while (*s == ' ') *s++ = '\0'
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.